# Send an email notification with the generated password on WooCommerce user creation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, email-notifications, user-data

In WooCommerce with code below I create new WP_User with a **random password** and set user role to "customer" (I want to create account on purchase automatically). Then I use `WC_Emails` to send login details to buyer. In that case I need plain password, but I really don't know why all other data are attached (username, name,...), but the password remains empty on the email notification.

My code is:

```
  // random password with 12 chars
$user_pass = wp_generate_password();

// create new user with email as username & newly created pw
$user_id = wp_create_user( $order_email, $user_pass, $order_email );
$user_id_role = new WP_User($user_id);
$user_id_role->set_role('customer');


$wc = new WC_Emails();
$wc->customer_new_account($user_id, $user_pass);




//WC guest customer identification
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'guest', 'yes' );

update_user_meta( $user_id, 'first_name', $order->billing_first_name );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'last_name', $order->billing_last_name );


//user's billing data
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_address_1', $order->billing_address_1 );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_address_2', $order->billing_address_2 );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_city', $order->billing_city );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_company', $order->billing_company );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_country', $order->billing_country );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_email', $order->billing_email );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_first_name', $order->billing_first_name );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_last_name', $order->billing_last_name );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_phone', $order->billing_phone );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_postcode', $order->billing_postcode );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_state', $order->billing_state );

// user's shipping data
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_address_1', $order->shipping_address_1 );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_address_2', $order->shipping_address_2 );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_city', $order->shipping_city );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_company', $order->shipping_company );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_country', $order->shipping_country );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_first_name', $order->shipping_first_name );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_last_name', $order->shipping_last_name );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_method', $order->shipping_method );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_postcode', $order->shipping_postcode );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_state', $order->shipping_state );

// link past orders to this newly created customer
wc_update_new_customer_past_orders( $user_id );
```

Any help or suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code regarding `WC_Order` properties that are not accessible anymore since WooCommerce 3 and replaced by getter and setter methods, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44708344/3730754)…

As you are creating some users programmatically, to send the Customer New Account email notification, you can use [`WC_Email_Customer_New_Account` `trigger()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Email_Customer_New_Account.html#89-114) method that has 3 arguments variables:

- `$user_id` -- The User ID (required)
- `$user_pass` -- The User password (optional) - Required in your case.
- `$password_generated` -- Whether the password was generated automatically or not (true or false). This optional argument displays the password on the email notification when is set to **`true`** *(default is false)*.

> To make the generated password displayed in "Customer New Account" email notification, **you also need to enable** in WooCommerce > Settings > Accounts & Privacy the option line:
>
> ***"When creating an account, automatically generate an account password"***

Once done, your working code is going to be:

```
// Customer Billing Email
$order_email = $order->get_billing_email();

// Generate a random password with 12 chars
$user_pass = wp_generate_password();

// Create new user with email as username & newly generated password
$user_id = wp_create_user( $order_email, $user_pass, $order_email );

$user = new WP_User($user_id); // Get the WP_User Object instance from user ID
$user->set_role('customer');   // Set the WooCommerce "customer" user role

// Get all WooCommerce emails Objects from WC_Emails Object instance
$emails = WC()->mailer()->get_emails();

// Send WooCommerce "Customer New Account" email notification with the password
$emails['WC_Email_Customer_New_Account']->trigger( $user_id, $user_pass, true );

//WC guest customer identification
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'guest', 'yes' );

update_user_meta( $user_id, 'first_name', $order->$order->get_billing_first_name() );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'last_name', $order->get_billing_last_name() );


//user's billing data
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_address_1', $order->get_billing_address_1() );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_address_2', $order->get_billing_address_2() );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_city', $order->get_billing_city() );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_company', $order->get_billing_company() );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_country', $order->get_billing_country() );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_email', $order_email );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_first_name', $order->get_billing_first_name() );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_last_name', $order->get_billing_last_name() );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_phone', $order->get_billing_phone() );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_postcode', $order->get_billing_postcode() );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_state', $order->get_billing_state() );

// user's shipping data
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_address_1', $order->get_shipping_address_1() );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_address_2', $order->get_shipping_address_2() );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_city', $order->get_shipping_city() );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_company', $order->get_shipping_company() );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_country', $order->get_shipping_country() );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_first_name', $order->get_shipping_first_name() );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_last_name', $order->get_shipping_last_name() );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_method', $order->get_shipping_method() );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_postcode', $order->get_shipping_postcode() );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_state', $order->get_shipping_state() );

// link past orders to this newly created customer
wc_update_new_customer_past_orders( $user_id );
```

Now as you will see a notification is sent to the customer, with its login and password, with the link to the login area...

[image]

---

**Template customizations for "Customer new account email":**

The related template path is `plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/customer-new-account.php`
and can be overridden by copying it to `yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/customer-new-account.php`

The available arguments (variables) passed to this template are:

- $email_heading -- The email_header,
- $user_login -- User Login,
- $user_pass -- User password,
- $blogname -- Title of the site,
- $password_generated -- Whether the password was generated automatically or not,
- $sent_to_admin  (false by default),
- $plain_text (false by default),
- $email -- The email instance Object.

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much. Works like a charm. Just learned something new! Thanks a lot

Comment: Loic, you are the best!

Comment: Perfect answer. 
Is this possible to copy woocommerce email templates in a custom plugin and edit it. By default, the email starts from Hi {username} which I want to change to Hi {first_name}.

Answer (score 0):

Try Enabling the below option and check if the mail contains the password.

This is not tested OK

[image]

Comment: I have this enabled from the beggining but doesn't work :(

Comment: @Karnak - How you creating the user account.? In checkout, there option to enter a password. On which hook/?

Comment: no, user doesn't have option to create account on checkout, because in our case every use must have account after checkout so we make it in code above on this line $user_id = wp_create_user( $order_email, $user_pass, $order_email );

Comment: If you disable guest checkout, every user will have to create an account, and option will be there to enter the password in checkout. It's default WC feature

Answer (score 0):

There's a much more straightforward way to do it that will spare you from a lot of boilerplate code: the WooCommerce [`wc_create_new_customer`](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-wc-user-functions.html#function_wc_create_new_customer) function.

If you only pass it the user email, it will take care of generating a password and a username and automatically send the new account email.

```php
wc_create_new_customer($order_email);
```

Just make sure that you have checked "automatically generate user account" and "automatically generate username" in *WooCommerce > Settings > Accounts*.

Also make sure you have enabled the account creation email in *WooCommerce > Settings > Emails*.