# Html tags inside Wordpress/Woocommerce add filter doesnt work

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have this code in wordpress theme function which modifies thankyou message after the order is completed.
It works but the html tags doesnt work. The line `<strong>For the delivery please</strong>` gets printed on the thankyou page as it is.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', 'cust_thankyou_text', 20, 2 );
   function cust_thankyou_text( $original_thankyou_text, $order ){
       if($order) {
    return $original_thankyou_text." <strong>For the delivery please</strong>";
       }
}
```

Why are html tags not working?

Comment: The hook `woocommerce_order_received_text`doesn't exist in WooCommerce core. The hook that exists is `woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text`.

Comment: yes thats what i am using woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text. I made this mistake in this question.

Comment: LooK at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77184675/3730754 answer thread, which question has the same problem than yours.

Comment: This is a [reported bug](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/40352) and will be solved in WooCommerce version 8.3.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the woocommerce_order_received_text filter to modify the thank you message, HTML won't work by default because the content needs to be sanitized to prevent security vulnerabilities.

You can use [wp_kses()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses/) function to sanitize:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_received_text', 'cust_thankyou_text', 20, 2 );
function cust_thankyou_text( $original_thankyou_text, $order ){
    if($order) {
        $thankyou_text = $original_thankyou_text." <strong>For the delivery please</strong>";
        return wp_kses( $thankyou_text, 'post' );
    }
}
```

Comment: It used to work last year. Did they update this.

Comment: @DineshThapa. Sorry, found out that this is actually a recent bug. 
It's been reported here: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/40352